# Is there any phrase to describe the situation when you try to do something but it always fails?

Tags: phrase-request

I would like to ask how  to describe a situation when you always try to do sth but it always fails. You always turn things upside down, is "I am just so in luck" enough?

Edit:
for instance whenever you buy a new car you have car accident , you buy new laptopt it will be damaged quickly .

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Do you mean, **clumsy**? (i.e., clumsy situation) http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/clumsy

Comment: Can you give us an example of a failure? Are you talking about physical problems like knocking things over, or social problems like saying the wrong thing? Money? Or just everything?

Comment: for instance whenever you buy a new car you have car accident , you buy new laptopt it will be damaged quickly .

Comment: This may be helpful: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187944/a-phrase-for-extremely-bad-luck

Comment: You might say "[Just my luck!](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/just-my-luck)"  This is an idiomatic saying that means, roughly, "This is the kind of fortune I always have!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a person buys things, the items may be damaged easily if:

1. Careless. - the person moves 'rashly', causing the damage
2. Clumsy. - the person isn't well coordinated, causing the damage
3. Unlucky. - the person is not careless nor clumsy, but *force majeure* (unavoidable accident) causes the damage.

So, based on your question, the person is just 'unlucky' or '**dogged by misfortune**'?

Answer (score 0):

You are subject to  *[Murphy's Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)*:

> Murphy's law is an adage or epigram that is typically stated as: Anything that can go wrong, will go wrong.

Example: When you drop a piece of toast  it will always land buttered side down.

See also [The ultimate collection of Murphy's laws](http://murphyslaws.net/).